# StringTokenizer returns null instead of String

Tags: string, stringtokenizer

The segment of code is meant to take a line of text pulled from a text file, separate it into separate tokens, and store each token in an index of an array. At first I thought the problem was with the text file, but putting the string into the editor directly didn't fix it.

With a string such as :

> "Chicken|None|Beast|Any|0|1|1|Hey Chicken!"

a StringTokenizer object with delimiter | returns the first four tokens as proper Strings, but null for the remaining four.

Interestingly enough, another String :

> "Gnoll|None|General|Any|2|2|2|Taunt|Taunt"

Will return the first five tokens as proper strings, but null for the remaining four as well.

If the problem is with the final four tokens, why is the StringTokenizer returning nulls in this fashion?

Code:

```
String[] parameter = new String[10];
String rawTxt = "Chicken|None|Beast|Any|0|1|1|Hey Chicken!";
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(rawTxt, "|");
for (int i = 0; i < t.countTokens(); i++) {
    parameter[i] = t.nextToken();
    System.out.print(parameter[i] + " ");
}
```

Output:

> Chicken None Beast Any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringTokenizer is deprecated so  should use String split method and it works for you code

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

 public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] parameter = new String[10];
    String rawTxt = "Chicken|None|Beast|Any|0|1|1|Hey Chicken!";
    String[] split = rawTxt.split("\\|");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the main problem is with improper use of `countToken()` in the conditional part of the `for` loop - because this number is reduced with each next token consumed.

That being sad, the following fix could be applied:

```
System.out.println("tokens: " + t.countTokens());
for (int i = 0, n = t.countTokens(); i < n; i++) {
    parameter[i] = t.nextToken();
    System.out.println("tokens left: " + t.countTokens() + ", " + parameter[i] + " ");
}
```

and it outputs correct results as expected:

```
tokens: 8
tokens left: 7, Chicken 
tokens left: 6, None 
tokens left: 5, Beast 
tokens left: 4, Any     <--- when i reaches 4 the condition i < t.countTokens() becomes false
tokens left: 3, 0 
tokens left: 2, 1 
tokens left: 1, 1 
tokens left: 0, Hey Chicken!
```